# using entsp in GSA - making no difference to the results

Tags: google-search-appliance

I was hoping someone had some experience using the `entsp` flag in GSA and was able to point out what I am doing wrong.  I've read the documentation but can't figure it out.

The query string I am passing through is:

```
?as_sitesearch=examplesite.com&callback=angular.callbacks._1&collection=hybrid_site_colection&entsp=a__di_site_biasing&frontend=jsonp&num=10&query=test&start=0
```

I've set up the biasing in the GSA, and when I apply it to the frontend itself, it behaves.  But I was hoping to pass it in dynamically, as I believed you could (we are likely to want to dynamically pass through one of a few biasing, depending on where the user is coming from), it makes no difference.

Am I missing a tag, or can someone see anything else wrong?

Comment: Thx for posting. I'm currently trying to use GSA metadata and entity biasing in a dynamic way, as you describe in the last paragraph of your question. Can you tell me how you accomplished this? I'm using XML instead of JSON which may make my question trickier - but perhaps knowing how you did it would help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, peoples, I've seen now that the problem is that we are going through a JSON bridge that isn't passing through my variables.

When I go directly to the GSA with a frontend, it works.